# Replace an underscore separated substring in the middle of a comma separated string

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have a file with multiple lines in it like this:

```
 'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}
```

I want to replace the 1371078139195 (in this case) with another number. 
The value I want to replace is always in the first comma separated word and is always the second last underscore separated value in that word. 
The following is the way I did this and it works but this seems unseemly and clumsy.

```
>>> line="'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}"
>>> l1=",".join(line.split(",")[1:])
>>> print l1
 {'cf:rv': '0'}
>>> l2=line.split(",")[0]
>>> print l2
'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_+14155186442'
>>> print "_".join(l2.split('_')[:-2])
'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight
>>>
>>> print "_".join(l2.split('_')[:-2])+ "_1234567_"+(l2.split('_')[-1])
'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1234567_+14155186442'
>>> print "_".join(l2.split('_')[:-2])+ "_1234567_"+(l2.split('_')[-1]) + "," + l1
'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1234567_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}
>>>
```

Is there an easier way to replace (maybe using regular expressions) the value? I can't imagine that this is the best way

I have a few answers and I have to stress that its the second last underscored value. The following are valid strings:

```
line = "'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_23456_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}"
line = "'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_23456_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}"
line = "'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_1371078139195_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_1371078139195', {'cf:rv': '0'}"
```

In the above case there is a digit string within the string that is not after the second last underscore. Also the last part may or may not be all digits (it could be +14155186442 or it could be 14155186442). Sorry I didn't mention this above.

A

Comment: Can you provide additional examples of entries? With only one example, I have no way of knowing just how far the entries vary from each other. Are the numbers always right next to each other? Does the second number always have a `+` in front of the digits? Can they instead have a `-` or something? More examples would make this question much easier to answer.

Comment: I added another one just there. Sorry I should have had more examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-regex solution:

```
>>> strs = " 'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}"
>>> first, sep, rest = strs.partition(',')
>>> lis = first.rsplit('_', 2)
>>> lis[1] = "1111111"
>>> "_".join(lis) + sep + rest
" 'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1111111_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}"
```

**Function:**

```
def solve(strs, rep):                                                                                                   first, sep, rest = strs.partition(',')
    lis = first.rsplit('_', 2)
    lis[1] = rep
    return "_".join(lis) + sep + rest
... 
>>> solve(" 'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}", "1111")
" 'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1111_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}"
>>> solve("'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_23456_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}", "2222")
"'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_23456_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_2222_14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}"
>>> solve("'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_1371078139195_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_1371078139195', {'cf:rv': '0'}", "2222")
"'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_1371078139195_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_2222_1371078139195', {'cf:rv': '0'}"
```

Comment: prettier than my solution

Comment: very nice but in the function form you need the line first, sep, rest = strs.partition(',') as sep and rest are not defined within the function

Comment: sorry I see now. It does not look like the partition line is there above but if you scroll across you find in on the same line as the def

Answer (score 4):

Using regular expressions:

```
m = re.match("([^,]*_)([+]?[0-9]+)(_.*)", s)
if m:
    before = m.group(1)
    number = m.group(2)
    after = m.group(3)
    s = before + new_number(number) + after
```

the meaning is

- `[^,]*_` = how many chars you want but not commas, followed by an underscore
- `[+]?[0-9]+` = digits, optionally preceded by `+`
- `_.*` = an underscore followed by whatever is there

This works because regexp matches are by default "greedy" so `[^,]*` will actually use all the underscore, stopping right before the second-last for the match to succeed.

If for example you need instead of the second-last underscore separated you need the third-last the expression could be changed to

```
m = re.match("([^,]*_)([+]?[0-9]+)(_[^,]*_.*)", s)
```

thus requiring that after the number there are at least two underscores before a comma.

Comment: that works for all but can you explain how [^,]*_ does not match up to the first number string in 'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_23456_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'} ? Is it just because it is using greedy grabs and if it were the third last underscore separated group this would not work?

Comment: @amadain: exactly. `[^,]*` grabs as much as possible so it will eat the first underscore. In your description the interesting part is after the last underscore in the first comma-separated value, so `[^,]*_` targets exactly that. It can however run in problems if the first value has an embedded comma, but looking at the data I thought this wasn't going to be the case.

Comment: no it would not be the case but I have cases where I want to extract the last or third last group. These are tables and the value i want to extract is an epoch time in millisecs so it'll always be all digits but other tables may have the other values as ints too so I need to specify where it is from the end of the string (underscore wise) on a per table basis

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
>>> line = "'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}"
>>> re.subn('_(\d+)_', '_mynewnumber_', line, count=1) 
("'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_mynewnumber_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}",
1)
```

Comment: Alternately, you could use `(?<=_)(\d+)(?=_)`, which makes it so you don't need to put underscores on each side of `mynewnumber`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

r = re.compile('([^,]*_)(\d+)(?=_[^_,]+,)(_.*)')

for line in ("'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}",
             "'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_23456_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}"):
    print line
    print r.sub('\\1ABCDEFG\\3',line)
    print r.sub('\g<1>1234567\\3',line)
```

result

```
'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}
'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_ABCDEFG_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}
'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1234567_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}

'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_23456_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}
'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_23456_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_ABCDEFG_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}
'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_23456_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1234567_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}
```

`\g<1>` means 'group 1'.
See in the doc:

> In addition to character escapes and backreferences as described
>   above, \g will use the substring matched by the group named
>   name, as defined by the (?P...) syntax. \g uses the
>   corresponding group number; \g<2> is therefore equivalent to \2, but
>   isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as \g<2>0. \20 would be
>   interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a reference to group 2
>   followed by the literal character '0'. The backreference \g<0>
>   substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.

Comment: Please, upvote **6502** user's answer, because ``(?=_[^_,]+,)`` in mine is apparently unncessary

Answer (score 0):

Not as sophisticated as a regex, but relatively simple to code, understand, debug, and change in the future. Other than the separator characters, it makes no assumptions about the what letters make up a "word".

```
def replace_term(line, replacement):
    csep = line.split(',')
    usep = csep[0].split('_')
    return ','.join(['_'.join(usep[:-2] + [replacement] + usep[-1:])] + csep[1:])

lines = ["'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_23456_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}",
         "'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_23456_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}",
         "'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_1371078139195_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_1371078139195_1371078139195', {'cf:rv': '0'}"]

for line in lines:
    print replace_term(line, 'XXX')
```

Output:

```
'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_23456_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_XXX_+14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}
'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_23456_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_XXX_14155186442', {'cf:rv': '0'}
'AMS_Investigation|txtt.co_1371078139195_BigtittedBlondOtherNight_XXX_1371078139195', {'cf:rv': '0'}
```